# How to connect react app to remote backend (asp.net) and make http request

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, axios, frontend, backend

thanks to all guys who read and reply on my post.

I have a **react app** and i have a remote server to which i need to make http request and fetch data.
**the backend is in asp.net** , usually when i am working on react-node i would add proxy:localhost:3000 in **package.json** file and its almost same when your backend is also on local system but i  have backend which is remote , how do i make http request.

**i have tried everything but it keeps giving this error:**

```
Eerrr fetching the data : Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:117:1)
```

**http request with axios::**

```
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://3.26.25.175:5001/api/v1/AdminPanel/status",

      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );
```

[image: error image]

Comment: check if you have CORS enabled on your asp.net backend.

Comment: @Wraithy Yes Mate , i have it enabled, still getting same issue , do you suggest something else. thanks alot really appreciate it .



we have this in our microservices and ocelot gateway                                                               






services.AddCors(confg =>
{
confg.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p =>
{
p.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader();
});
});

Comment: and do you see some error in browser console or network tab?

Comment: @Wraithy yes during api call  in try catch  when i console log i only see Net error. and sometime i see CORS problem , kindly view the error image i provided.thanky you

Comment: You propably have self signed certificate here.... easiest solution is to open this endpoint in new tab and accept certificate in browser or add certificate as trusted root browser to OS